# How to create recurring notifications in Rails from an admin interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job, recurring

I would like to create a new function in my survey app that lets users set daily, weekly etc. notifications about the stats of their surveys. Also I would like to let users delete these notifications if they don't need them anymore, or their survey ends.

It seems fairly simple to create a Notification model, which stores the necessary information about the notification, but how do I schedule it to send out the e-mail with the stats daily, weekly ( whatever the user sets ) etc.

Sure I can use delayed_job or resque and reschedule everytime but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Any ideas how to make this happen in the most elegant, and efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem useful

here's an example syntax for it:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end
```

Comment: Hi Maciek! Thanks for the input. I know the whenever gem and I use it regularly, for example to create/update sitemaps. But I am not sure how to activate/deactivate a recurring task in it from a web interface.

Comment: hmm... maybe you could write a cron that checks which users needs notifications and send it accordingly ? This may take a while if you have a lot of users, so I would probably use [sidekiq][https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq] worker for it